# Django: No HttpResponse when passing value to function Jquery / Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Currently I have two buttons one to define my api search to the activites category and one to define it to the restaurant category, I am looking to post the data to my views.py folder and get a response. My function located within my views.py folder that look something like this.

```
@csrf_exempt
def json_request(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'category' in request.GET:
            category = request.GET['category']


            return HttpResponse('category')

        return HttpResponse('failed')
```

This is to test whether the variable 'category' gets sent through. My onclick interaction is like this:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var URL = "{% url 'test' %}";
    </script>

    <script>
        function updateCategory(){
            var data = {'category': category}
            $.get(URL, data, function(response){
                if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }
                else{ alert('Error! :('); }
            });
 }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnRestaurant').click(function(){
                category = "restuarant";
                updateCategory();
            });
            $('#btnActive').click(function(){
                category = "active";
                updateCategory();
            });
        });
</script>
```

And my buttons are like this:

```
     <button name ="category" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id=btnRestaurant onclick=" updateCategory()">Food</button>
<button name="categoryA" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id=btnActive onclick="updateCategory()">Activites</button>
```

Now the odd thing is when I click the button for each I receive the alert('Yay!') but as it tries to update the page I receive I get back this error:

**The view project_name.views.json_request didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

Also if it helps I will add in my url search from my urls.py

```
    url(r"^loc_search/", 'project_name.views.json_request', name="test"),
```

I am completely bewildered I feel like someone is going to point it out immediately but I really need a hand figuring out just what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're not preventing the button's default action, which is to submit the page without Javascript. So your Ajax fires, but then the normal browser submission happens. And this appears to be a GET not a POST, which your view does not support.

Make sure your `click` functions accept the `event` parameter, and call `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Also, make sure that your view handles GET requests properly - at least by returning a 405 (using  `HttpResponseNotAllowed` https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed)

Comment: When you say to submit the page without java script, do you mean I just need to declare it at the top?

Comment: I have altered the code per yoru suggestions and I now get a HttpResponse but it failed  :/

Answer (score 0):

Default button type is `submit`

So. Try this by adding `type="button"`.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id=btnRestaurant onclick="updateCategory()">Food</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id=btnActive onclick="updateCategory()">Activites</button>
```

**Updated**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def json_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'category' in request.POST:
        # your code
```

Note `csrf_token` is must.It is for just escape from it now.

Comment: Just added it in but still no http response :(

Comment: Is it now alert "yay" ?

Comment: I sorted it need a GET not a POST but its failed :/

Comment: What means failed ? , error code, One thing, you are not sending CSRF TOKEN.Try with `@csrf_exempt` \

Comment: The GET was sent through but my user inputed HttpResponse('failed') was returned

Comment: Why are you using GET,? POST will work, check my edit.GET retruns failed because `if request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: Oh no i changed all of that ill update it to show you what its like at the minute

Comment: If i use post by the way it doesnt even gie me a http response :/

Comment: it doesnt outright fail but I recieve my pre defined HttpResponse('failed')

Comment: `if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }` ? or `if(response === 'category'){ alert('Yay!'); }`   ?

Comment: Change it to cartegory because you are sending category from view